USB to RS232 open ended cable doesn't work whereas one with adapter works
I have this open-ended USB-RS232 cable USB-RS232-WE-1800-BT_0.0, another cable with adapter Startech ICUSB2321F, and this device PRDSTU251C that I want to connect with my PC.
I can connect with the device using the startech adapter but when I try to do so using the open-ended cable, my program doesn't detect the antenna reader. I am very sure that I made the connections right on the open-ended cable (crossing TX/ RX, CTS/ RTS), level inverting by modifying eeprom so that CTS#/ RTS# become CTS/ RTS respectively. However, upon reading the default values for the working startech adapter, it didn't have the `Invert RTS#' and 'Invert CTS#' flags enabled, so, I reverted to the original settings in the open-ended cable.
This is the pin configuration for the RFID reader (or DCE as we call in RS232 terminology)

and this is for the open-ended cable, all from the datasheets in the links.

This is how I am connecting the cables.

I also tried to play around with testing the voltage levels on the RFID reader pins and the bare USB cable/ connector pins to see what they actually transmit and found that the startech adapter had both -ve and +ve voltage ranges (-8 to +5 V) whereas the open-ended cable only had 0 to +5 V readings.
The startech website also mentions this information. I couldn't find any similar information for the RFID reader requirements.

It has been a long time since I worked deeply with serial protocols. Could somebody please explain what's happening here? Is this open-ended cable not suitable for this? Does it require extra circuitry to make it work? Does Startech have anything extra besides the FT232R chip inside their adapter?
Update
Gotcha! I just confirmed with my colleague. The one that I have is this cable (www.amazon.com/dp/B073RGLD85) which is 5V TTL. I didn't doubt it because both Digikey and amazon cable use the same chip with the difference being the voltage level shifter. Thanks all for the help and sorry for the inconvenience. Now, the picture is clear to me.

I would first check my drivers for the cable, then use a terminal to see if I get any signals out of the cable whatsoever.

You link to a FTDI RS-232 cable which is a correct product you need, but if your cable uses 0V/5V voltages, maybe you have a different cable than you think? What reads on the bottom of the cable which exact type it is?

I agree with the above comment. Can you confirm you have the exact product you link on DigiKey? Please take photos of it if you can.

Gotcha! I just confirmed with my colleague. The one that I have is https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073RGLD85?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title which is 5V TTL. I didn't doubt it because both Digikey and amazon cable use the same chip with the difference being the voltage level shifter. Thanks all for the help and sorry for the inconvenience. Now, the picture is clear to me.

@you_know_who Dang that sucks. This update makes the answer below 100% correct and it won’t let me change my downvote to an upvote anymore. Regardless, you should vote on it yourself and accept the answer if you can.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

There are two kinds of "RS232" these days. The protocol and bit rate is the same but the physical interfaces are opposite.

True RS232: Logic 1 is -12 V or -5 V. Logic 0 is +12 or +5 V. This is what you'll find on a DE9 connector, or even a DB25, ha ha.

The "Arduino" or Logic Level serial port, aka "FTDI cable". +5V for logic 1, 0 V for logic 0. Never on a 9-pin D connector, it usually has pins for a breadboard, or dupont-type sockets on wires, or a 4-pole 0.1" molex connector. If the microcontroller Vcc is 3.3 V then the logic 1 is also 3.3 V.


Type 2 is what would come directly out of the microcontroller's UART. Traditionally then a MAX232 type chip would be used to convert to real RS232, but as PCs don't come with RS232 ports, it's much simpler all round to just use the TTL levels and skip the two MAX232s.
So you probably have some USB adapters of different types.  For example, FTDI makes both kinds and you can easily confuse the two.  The one you linked in your question is Type 1, but they also make a Type 2 that looks nearly identical with the same exact wire colors.  Make sure you have the correct one for your application (which sounds like should be Type 1).

But the FTDI cable datasheet shows a circuit schematic with a MAX232-style charge-pump level shifter IC right after the FTDI chip.

There's only one kind of RS-232. The other thing you talk about is not RS-232. The FTDI cable is a real RS-232 cable, without a DE9 connector.

@tomnexus True the voltmeter does not lie but the cable type it is said to be is true RS-232 cable, so OP may have a different cable than assumed. Also, based on your logic, there's three types of RS-232 : (1) Actual RS-232, (2) direct  logic level UART signaling with no relation to RS-232 at all and (3) Pseudo-RS232 sent as logic levels but inverted so that a typical RS-232 compatible receiver might be able to receive it. Also, there is no DB9 connector, you must mean the normal DE9 connector.

@tomnexus  The questioner made a recent update to the question saying they linked the wrong product.  I updated your question to clarify that FTDI branded cables can come in both types.  This should be the accepted answer and I tagged the questioner to consider accepting it.

@tomnexus Agreed. I didn’t even know FTDI made Type 1’s until I saw the linked DigiKey product. I figured if someone posts a DigiKey link of something they bought they would copy/paste it directly from their order history….but I guess not. You saw through the lies!
